# Is There an Upper Bound in my locale for Time Related Information?

Tags: c++, boost, c++-chrono, ctime, boost-locale

Is there a definition somewhere in the standard namespace that sets forward:

1. Months in a year
2. Days in a week
3. Hours in a day
4. Minutes in an hour
5. Seconds in a minute

The [struct tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) has contains member variables that must be in these ranges, but I can't find the defined limits anywhere.

I'm not even sure if there are locales defined where these wouldn't match the conventional set (12/7/24/60/60).

Even if there aren't potential users with other range limits, I'd sure like to use a define from the standard namespace rather than arbitrarily defining my own.

**EDIT:**

It looks like I'm not the first to ask for such a thing: http://david.tribble.com/text/c0xcalendar.html
I notice in this proposal there is mention of the `struct calendarinfo` which does exactly what I'm looking for.

It looks like the last change on this was 2009. I guess nothing's happened since then? I guess that also means this stuff is not readily available to me?

More info, [boost::locale::calendar::maximum](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/locale/doc/html/classboost_1_1locale_1_1calendar.html#abd88cbf4c3b9f072430f9e7d9ab2d744) seems to accomplish exactly what I'm looking for. I can't use Boost, but I'm certain that the code in Boost *is* the defacto standard on how to come up with these limits. Unfortuantely I can't seem to get at the implementation of `maximum`. Maybe someone else here knows how?

Comment: If you look at the Hebrew calendar you can see that it is different.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar

Comment: @NathanOliver interesting, so I guess this may have a real world use case beyond just a standardized limit definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C and C++ standards say absolutely nothing about any calendar except the Gregorian calendar, and not a lot about that one.

**`1.` Months in a year**

The only thing you'll find is a comment in the C standard beside the `tm_mon` member of `tm`:

```
int tm_mon;  // months since January -- [0, 11]
```

Well, almost only.  You'll also find `%b` and `%B` specifiers in `strftime` which correspond to the current locale's abbreviated and full month names corresponding to `tm_mon`.

**`2.`  Days in a week**

You've got:

```
int tm_wday;  // days since Sunday -- [0, 6]
```

and `%a`, `%A` for `strftime`.

**`3.` Hours in a day**

You've got:

```
int tm_hour;  // hours since midnight -- [0, 23]
```

There's also `strftime` specifiers, a few of which are sensitive to the current locale.

**`4.` Minutes in an hour**

```
int tm_min;  // minutes after the hour -- [0, 59]
```

Also in this case you've got some help from the new C++11 `<chrono>` library:

```
std::cout << std::chrono::hours{1}/std::chrono::minutes{1} << '\n';
```

This will portably (and consistently) output `60`.  If your compiler supports `constexpr` and you are worried about efficiency, this quantity can be a compile-time integral constant:

```
constexpr auto minutes_per_hour = std::chrono::hours{1}/std::chrono::minutes{1};
```

The type of `minutes_per_hour` is guaranteed to be signed integral and at least 29 bits.

**`5.` Seconds in a minute**

The C spec is a little interesting on this one:

```
int tm_sec;  // seconds after the minutes -- [0, 60]
```

The range is not documented as `[0, 59]` so as to allow for the addition of a positive leap second.  That being said, no OS that I'm aware of actually implements an accurate accounting of leap seconds.  Everyone appears to follow [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which tracks UTC except ignoring leap seconds.  When a leap second occurs, all OS's I'm aware of simply treat it as an ordinary clock correction.  Google famously treats it as a [smear of corrections over some window of time](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/time-technology-and-leaping-seconds.html).

Additionally you can consistently and portably write:

```
std::cout << std::chrono::minutes{1}/std::chrono::seconds{1} << '\n';
```

and get `60`.

---

While not defined by the C or C++ standards, every OS appears to be measuring time since New Years 1970 ([neglecting leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).  In C++11 this quantity is available via:

```
auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

where `tp` will have type `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.  This `time_point` has an unspecified precision (fortnights, seconds, femtoseconds, whatever). The precision is programmatically discoverable at compile time.

---

In case it is helpful, [this link](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) contains code which can translate `tp` into year/month/day hour:minute:second and even fractions of a second (and vice-versa). Oh, day-of-week if you want it too (and several other calendrical tricks).  This public domain code depends on the *non-standard* but de-facto portable epoch of New Years 1970.  It could easily be adopted to other epochs if the need ever arises.

Comment: When I started reading I was scared you were just gonna regurgitate the information from my `struct tm` link. But your comments on 4 and 5 were really genius. I wonder if there's a way to accomplish something similar on 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can create your own custom `chrono::duration` units like this: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IStPNCZvSfOH5Cfr and then divide them to back the conversion constants back out of them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I can conclusively say that there is *not* a define for any of these numbers in `namespace std`.

I am basing this statement on the fact that Boost's [gregorian.cpp](https://github.com/boostorg/locale/blob/master/src/util/gregorian.cpp) hard codes all of these values in `get_value`

If you do have Boost, you are able to leverage `get_value` to find "Months in a year", "Days in a week", and "Hours in a day" by doing:

```
locale::global(boost::locale::generator()(""));
cout.imbue(locale());

boost::locale::date_time now;

cout << "Months in a year: " << now.maximum(boost::locale::period::period_type(boost::locale::period::marks::month)) << endl;
cout << "Days in a week: " << now.maximum(boost::locale::period::period_type(boost::locale::period::marks::day_of_week)) << endl;
cout << "Hours in a day: " << now.maximum(boost::locale::period::period_type(boost::locale::period::marks::hour)) << endl;
```

Which outputs:

> Months in a year: 11
>   Days in a week: 7
>   Hours in a day: 23

<sub>Note the 0-based months and hours and the 1-based days. This is consistant with [put_time](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/put_time/?kw=put_time)'s `%u` flag.</sub>

If you do not have Boost you'll need to define these yourself.

[Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant)'s solution for finding "Minutes in an hour" and "Seconds in a minute" *is* actually based in defines from `namespace std`:

```
cout << "Minutes in an hour: " << chrono::hours{1} / chrono::minutes{1} << endl;
cout << "Seconds in a minute: " << chrono::minutes{1} / chrono::seconds{1} << endl;
```

Which outputs:

> Minutes in an hour: 60
>   Seconds in a minute: 60