# Extract date timestamp from a timestamp in C++

Tags: c++, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How can I extract a date (YYYY-MM-DD) from a timestamp and save it as a timestamp?
We know that `1518038663000` is `Wednesday, 7 February 2018 16:24:23`(GTM -5 hours) yet I would like to keep just `Wednesday, 7 February 2018`(GTM -5 hours) and save it as `1517979600000`

Comment: Look here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use this [free, open-source time zone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), this can be done like so:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using date::operator<<;

    // set up the timestamp
    date::sys_time<milliseconds> ts{1518038663000ms};

    // create a zoned_time by pairing the timestamp with a time_zone
    auto zt = date::make_zoned("America/New_York", ts);

    // confirm what you have by printing out the timestamp and the local time
    std::cout << zt.get_sys_time().time_since_epoch() << '\n';
    std::cout << date::format("%A, %e %B %Y %T (%z)", zt) << "\n\n";

    // Truncate the zoned_time to the beginning of the local day
    zt = date::floor<date::days>(zt.get_local_time());

    // confirm what you have by printing out the timestamp and the local time
    std::cout << zt.get_sys_time().time_since_epoch() << '\n';
    std::cout << date::format("%A, %e %B %Y %T (%z)", zt) << '\n';
}
```

The comments in the code above describe what each line of code is doing.  The single line of code in the middle is the actual answer to this question:

```
    // Truncate the zoned_time to the beginning of the local day
    zt = date::floor<date::days>(zt.get_local_time());
```

This program outputs:

```
1518038663000ms
Wednesday,  7 February 2018 16:24:23.000 (-0500)

1517979600000ms
Wednesday,  7 February 2018 00:00:00.000 (-0500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously random numbers said to be timestamps only have value if they also have units. For the number "1518038663000" to equate to "Wednesday, 7 February 2018 16:24:23" it implies that we are working in milliseconds since the epoch. Given such units we can convert the timestamp to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)'s [`chrono::duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration): `const chrono::milliseconds ts(1518038663000);`

From `chrono::milliseconds` we'll need to cast to a `chrono::duration` representing days. Unfortunately the chrono library's convenience function with the longest `period` is `hours` thus we'll need to define our own `chrono::duration`. Since the `period` is defined as:

> The number of seconds per tick

We'll need to calculate the number of seconds in a day, [unfortunately that's not defined in the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28548634/2642059), but we can calculate it: `ratio<86400>` (or to be more explicit: `ratio_multiply<chrono::hours::period, ratio<24>>`).

Next we'll need to decide the rounding we want to use: [What's the Difference Between floor and duration_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468068/whats-the-difference-between-floor-and-duration-cast) But it's probably [`chrono::floor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/floor). So we'll truncate to days then convert back to milliseconds to store the value:

```
const auto result = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::floor<chrono::duration<int, ratio<86400>>>(ts))
```

As far as output formatting for `result` you'll want to use [`put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) which means you'll need to convert as follows:

```
const auto time = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::time_point(result));

cout << put_time(localtime(&time), "%A,%e %B %Y");
```

The timestamp that you'll want to store will be: `result.count()`.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1da564671cfda22c)

Comment: If the input to your program is 1518038663000, is the output 1517979600000?  If not, what is the nature of the discrepancy between what you output, and what the OP reports?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Since you know more about this library than I do, I assume you are pointing out a potential pitfall with depending simply upon the standard. My clamp to days is absolute, it doesn't consider a GMT offset. If such an offset needs to be preserved it will need to be added back in. That's really as simple as doing `+ chrono::hours(5)`, so your `result` calculation would become: `const auto result = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::floor<chrono::duration<int, ratio<86400>>>(ts)) + chrono::hours(5)`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27ae602bdae9004d